# For odd $n$ is the polynomial $X^{n-1}-X^{n-2}+...-X+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $n$ be an odd integer. Is the polynomial $X^{n-1}-X^{n-2}+...-X+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?
I believe that it is, but I don't know how to ptove it. I tried to use Eisenstein's criterion, but it would only work when $n$ is prime. So, how to do it?

Comment: By replacing $X$ with $-X$ you end up with $1+X+X^2+\ldots+X^{n-1}$ which is the product of the *cyclotomic polynomials* $\Phi_k$ for $k|n$, $k > 1$ (each of them is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ but it’s not super easy).

Comment: If $d| n$, your polynomial is divisible by $X^{d-1}-X^{d-2}+\ldots-X+1$.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=9$. Then your polynomial $P_n$ factors (as mentioned in comments) as $\Phi_3(-x)\Phi_9(-x)$ where the $\Phi$ are cyclotomic polynomials. In general $P_n=\prod_{d\mid n,d>1}\Phi_d(-x)$, so it is irreducible precisely when $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

It's a (not too difficult) theorem that $d|n$ iff $(x^{d}-1)|(x^n-1)$. Factoring out $x-1$ and letting $n$ be odd should answer your question.

To prove the theorem, you only need the forward direction (which is the easier one). Just suppose $a$ is a root of $x^d -1$ and that $n= dk$. Then  $a^d = a^{dk} = 1$, so $a$ is a root of $x^n - 1$.